# Is there a way to set an alarm for sunrise, whenever that may be?

Tags: iphone, ios, alarm

The title pretty much says it all.  I've been wanting a "Sunrise alarm" for some time, but have never been able to find a way to do it - at least not a free one.  In addition to much experimentation with the built-in alarms, I've tried I think every free app in the store that claims to do this, and literally not a single one has worked (they all fail in various horrendously bad ways).

Is there a free way to set a simple sunrise alarm?  Failing that, is there any low-cost (like under $5) app that will actually do this well, and works on iOS 12?

Comment: what machine and system version are you running?

Comment: iPhone SE iOS 12.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered that this is built-in to the Amazon Alex app.  You can create a "Routine" that triggers on sunrise or sunset (or a variety of other things of course) based on any given location.  Can do a lot more than a simple alarm too... can trigger home automation devices or do all kinds of other stuff.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a shortcut within the Shortcuts app for this.

[image]

The coordinates in the first command need to be replaced with those of the location you need the alarm for.

PS: The alert will show the UTC time, but the alarm itself will be created in the local timezone of the iPhone/iPad